# ComboBox KeyValuePair not getting values properly

Tags: c#, combobox, key-value, keyvaluepair

```
  /**Dictionary looks like this
    *[PERCENTAGELOSS, 0]
    *[THRESHOLD, 1]
    *etc.
    */
  Dictionary<string, string> allEnums = XMLHandling.getEnums(enumCognityName);

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in allEnums)
        {
             enumCmb.Items.Add(item);
        }
             enumCmb.DisplayMember = "Key";
             enumCmb.ValueMember = "Value";
             enumCmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

After I add the `KeyValuePairs` to the `ComboBox`, it correctly displays the names of the items, but I can't get their values properly. Here's the code that tries to get the values:

```
case "enum":
           ComboBox enumBox = c as ComboBox;
           var test0 = enumBox.SelectedItem; // [PERCENTAGELOSS, 0]
           var test1 = enumBox.SelectedText; // ""
           var test2 = enumBox.SelectedValue; // null
           break;
```

I thought I correctly added the `ValueMember` as the "Value" from the `KeyValuePair`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember only work when you set the DataSource of the ComboBox.  SelectedItem should work, you just have to cast it to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding items in enumCmb, you can bind like this

```
enumCmb.DisplayMember = "Key";
enumCmb.ValueMember = "Value";
enumCmb.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = allEnums };
```

I'm not sure but you may need to cast your data to list.

Comment: Worked marvelously, didn't even have to cast the data to a list! Thank you!